# Is it possible to use BYTEA fields with Spring Data JDBC (not JPA)

Tags: spring, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to read a row in a Postgresql table that has a BYTEA field, using Spring Data JDBC, and it's failing with a `Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type byte!` MappingException.  The method is failing in `org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.EntityRowMapper.populateProperties`, where it's interpreting `byte[]` as `isCollectionLike` and (I suppose) trying to create SQL to read it as a PostgreSQL array of bytes, rather than the blob it is.

There's plenty of examples for how to do this with JPA or manual JdbcTemplate, but the documentation for Spring Data JDBC is less rich.  I can't imagine I'm the first one to hit this issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at markscottwright.Application.main(Application.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type byte!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.SqlGeneratorSource.lambda$getSqlGenerator$0(SqlGeneratorSource.java:41) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.SqlGeneratorSource.getSqlGenerator(SqlGeneratorSource.java:40) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.sql(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:360) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.findAllByProperty(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.EntityRowMapper.populateProperties(EntityRowMapper.java:94) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.EntityRowMapper.mapRow(EntityRowMapper.java:74) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:678) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:693) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:747) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:227) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.findAll(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:217) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.findAll(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:171) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.findAll(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:84) ~[spring-data-jdbc-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at markscottwright.Application.run(Application.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2019-08-20 13:36:00.335  INFO 10604 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-08-20 13:36:00.344  INFO 10604 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

My table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_entity (
    id                              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    byte_array                      BYTEA
    );

insert into test_entity values (1, decode('00010203', 'hex'));
```

TestEntity.java

```java
package markscottwright;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public byte[] byteArray;
}
```

TestEntityRepository.java

```java
package markscottwright;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TestEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
}
```

My Application.java

```java
package markscottwright;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.EnableJdbcRepositories;

@EnableJdbcRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityRepository testEntities;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        testEntities.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>markscottwright</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdata-bytea</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was implemented as part of [DATAJDBC-327](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-327) and [DATAJDBC-259](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-259) they are available in the 1.1.x builds.

The most current one is 1.1.0.RC2 available from the milestone repository https://repo.spring.io/milestone